# sparx Enterprise Architect BPMN simulation step into and out of child models (composite models)

Tags: enterprise-architect

In BPMN 2, if I create a context-menu=>new child diagram=>Composite Structure Diagram within the same package, then the simulation navigates to it and also back out to the parent.

However, when I link to a BPMN2 diagram in another package via context-menu=>new child diagram=>select Componsite Diagram then the simulation-navigation no longer works. What am I missing?

Possible/Tips? 
Registered Enterprise Architect (Professional Edition) 14.0.1421

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are not so many EA-BPMN-simulation users here. So you probably want to cross-post on Sparx' forum too.

Comment: You are probably not using BPMN in EA correctly. There are many gotcha's to avoid. Having to set a random diagram as the composite diagram is a sign that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thx. It is another BPMN, is that random?

Comment: It looks like also on Sparx' forum you don't get feedback. You might contact Sparx' support via mail. Usually they are quite responsive.

Comment: The sparx support has recognized two bugs related to swimlanes and event-ends which confuse the simulation. They claim to be fixing these now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from Sparx Support:

> With the BPMN simulation this is restricted to a single package. As
>   the BPMN (and in particular the BPMN XML) is basically restricted to a
>   Model in a Package, it is not intended to support references to
>   elements contained in other packages.
>
> If you are intending separating elements you might consider doing this
>   with Pools.
>
> I hope this is of help.

Comment: Sigh why have such a feature at all if it can't even be used in something else than a trivial example. I still consider this a bug.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I'd just call that bad design. It's probably one of those sales features.

Comment: Sadly, the feature is a bit buggy. Nice idea though. https://www.sparxsystems.com.au/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_simulation/model_simulation.html

Comment: See comment above. Some bugs confirmed.